# How to avoid grouping if the field value is null in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

For example, this is my data:

```
[
    { movieName: null, artistName : "Arrow to Athens", song: "Dust & Gold" },
    { movieName: null, artistName : "Arrow to Athens" song: "Alive" },
    { movieName: "Raaz", artistName : "KK" song: "Soniyo" }
]

const movieList = await model.aggregate([
            {$group: { _id: "$movieName", albumName: { $first: "$albumName" }, movieName: { $first: "$movieName" } } }
        ])
```

After using group by clause, I am getting output like this

```
[{movieName: "null"
artistName: "Arrow to Athens"
_id: "null"
},
{movieName: "Raaz"
artistName: "KK"
_id: "Raaz"
}]
```

Expected output

```
[{movieName: "Raaz"
artistName: "KK"
_id: "Raaz"
}]
```

This means it should avoid grouping if field value is null how can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your group stage, you can just add a `$match` stage which filters out values you don't want. For example:

```
$match: {
   movieName: { $ne: null }
}
```

The [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) in value `{ $ne: null }` is short for "not equals".